# Как задать относительный путь для создания файла в C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, файлы, visual-studio-2015

Как задать путь для файла в текущую папку с программой  или относительно текущей папки с исполнительным файлом?

```
while (match.Success)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("opinios.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        while (match.Success)
        {
            writer.WriteLine("\"" + match.Groups[1].Value + "\"");
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
    }
}
```

Так как в этом случае выдаёт такую ошибку:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Отказано в доступе по пути
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\opinios.csv".

А задавать полный путь аля D:..... не вариант

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory`

Comment: @Bulson это вернет путь к рабочей папке, а не исполняемому файлу

Comment: @tym32167 да, но в простых учебных программках эти понятия равнозначны.

Comment: @Bulson какое это имеет значение в контексте данного вопроса? Автор просит путь к папке с исполняемым файлом, вы советуете путь к рабочему каталогу - я указал, что это не одно и то же, чтобы никого не путать, кто будет это потом читать.

Comment: @tym32167 хорошо, хорошо, пусть будет все точно и ясно.

Answer (score 8):

Для начала, вам нужно получить каталог, из которого стартовала программа.
Это вполне может быть **не** текущий каталог, если кто-нибудь запустит программу по полному пути из другого каталога. (Ну или если программа сама возьмёт и сменит текущий каталог.)

Для этого используйте

```
var appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Чтобы задать относительный путь, используйте `Path.Combine`:

```
var relativePath = @"subdir\opinios.csv";
var fullPath = Path.Combine(appDir, relativePath);
```

---

Кстати, запись в каталог программы — не самая лучшая идея. Дело в том, что в реальных условиях программа будет находиться в защищённом от записи каталоге внутри Program Files. Требовать администраторских привилегий — плохой путь, вы при этом сможете при ошибке обрушить всю систему. Рекомендованное место, куда можно писать файлы вашей программе — либо подкаталог каталога Documents (для документов, которые создаются для пользователей), либо подкаталог каталога AppData (для файлов, которые нужны только вашей программе):

```
var baseFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
// или
var baseFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
var appStorageFolder = Path.Combine(baseFolder, "Имя Вашей Программы");
var fullPath = Path.Combine(appStorageFolder, relativePath);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, долго мучился, твой вариант выручил)

Comment: @AleksandrEfimov: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @AleksandrEfimov, если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ на ваш вопрос, отметьте его как принятый (зеленая галочка под рейтингом ответа)