# Папка создается не в нужном месте C#

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Написал приложение-1 на C#, которое создает папку. Основное приложение-2 качает его, и закидывает в другую папку внутри себя, что-то вроде "firstApp\secondApp\приложение-1.exe", после чего приложение-2 запускает приложение-1, которое создает папку не в secondApp\firstApp\приложение-1-folder, а в secondApp\приложение-1-folder. При этом, когда вручную запускать приложение-2, оно работает как нужно и создает папку в secondApp\firstApp\приложение-1-folder. То есть при запуске приложения-1 из вне, оно создает директорию не внутри себя, а в корне каталога, из которого была запущена. Как решается данная проблема?

### Код приложения-2, которое запускает приложение-1

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(DownloadName, DownloadName.Remove(DownloadName.Length - 4));
Process.Start(DownloadName.Remove(DownloadName.Length - 4) + "\\" + DownloadName.Replace(".zip", ".exe"), "-sd");
```

### Код приложения-1, которое создает папку

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("data");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо указать рабочую директорию приложения, проще всего это сделать в свойствах ярлыка, который будет запускать ваше приложение. В свойствах назначенного задания, также присутствует аналогичная настройка.
Внутри кода программ,это можно сделать так

```
string exeDir =Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(exeDir);
```

Comment: В гугле по запросу "Как указать рабочую директорию приложения c#" не нашел ответа на свой вопрос. Так что вопрос остается открытым. Если не трудно, дайте сорсы, либо напишите код. Кстати вариант запуска приложения с ярлыка не подходит, ибо файл распаковывается из архива.

Answer (score 4):

Путь папки приложения.

```csharp
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string path = Application.StartupPath;
```

Comment: `Application.StartupPath` — это только для WinForms. Для приложений командной строки нужен немного более сложный код.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не должны использовать относительные пути, если не хотите таких сюрпризов.

Дело в том, что относительный путь — это путь относительно текущего каталога, а не относительно положения программы на диске. (Нет, это не одно и то же.) Программа сама **не контролирует** стартовое значение текущего каталога, поэтому либо она должна в самом начале устанавливать его, либо просто всегда работать с полными путями.

Связанный вопрос: [Как определяется каталог поиска файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/746097/10105)

О том, как получить каталог, в котором лежит приложение, здесь: [Как задать относительный путь для создания файла в C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/743357/10105)